# Dynamic Variable in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this code :

```
var dynamicVarName = id;

var percentage = res.parkeren[0].dynamicVarName.percentage;
```

DynamicvarName can have different values, but when i call this in the var percentage it's not working.

How can i get the dynamic variable in the array / object?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need the [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation) for the access:

```
var dynamicVarName = 'id';
var percentage = res.parkeren[0][dynamicVarName].percentage
```